# Perl: Convert string to number (NOT literally!)

Tags: string, perl, numbers, radix

I want to convert a string to number. You might read this as I want to convert "5" into 5, but no.

The conversion should be like this:

```
"aa" -> 24929
"55" -> 13621
"sebastian" -> 2128681077170648998254
"SEBASTIAN" -> 1536070381281124893006
\xFF\xFF -> 65536
```

Ergo, treat the input character string as a base^256 number, and convert it accordingly.

In the same way, I want also to be able to convert numbers back into their char representation.

How can I accomplish this in perl?

Comment: Try using a `for` loop and the `chr` method.

Comment: @EliSadoff Yes I know I can for loop it, and then multiply it with different amounts of 256's, but Im searching for a more "efficient" method. Also converting back becomes a tedious task with modulus if theres not some more efficient method.

Comment: Then have a look at [Math::Base::Convert](http://search.cpan.org/~miker/Math-Base-Convert-0.08/Convert.pm). They advertise arbitrary base conversion.

Comment: @PerlDuck : "not a valid base: 256 at /var/www/index.cgi line 24"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $n = unpack("Q>", substr(("\0"x8) . $s, -8));
```

However, that won't handle the numbers for `sebastian` and `SEBASTIAN` since they are too large for Perl's native types (64 bits, so 8 bytes). You'd need an library that provides more precision (such as [Math::Int128](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Int128)) or one that provides an arbitrary amount of precision (such as [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigInt)).

Fastest, but limited to 128 bits (16 bytes):

```
use Math::Int128 qw( net_to_uint128 );

my $n = net_to_uint128(substr(("\0"x16) . $s, -16));
```

or

```
use Math::Int128 qw( hex_to_uint128 );

my $n = hex_to_uint128(unpack('H*', $s));
```

Require best performance from Math::BigInt:

```
use Math::BigInt only => 'GMP';

my $n = Math::BigInt->from_hex(unpack('H*', $s));
```

Falls back to slower code if GMP is not available:

```
use Math::BigInt try => 'GMP';

my $n = Math::BigInt->from_hex(unpack('H*', $s));
```

Comment: Number "7305508694050562414" is equal to "ebastian" and number 4990623163232108878 is equal to "EBASTIAN" so you propably missed out on the first character. Or the function you wrote is limited to 8 characters. But it might work anyways. Should try it out... Im currently messing around with a 3DES library and a session string, so I will propably be able to work it out block-wise.